# Translating a String containing a binary value to Hex

Tags: java, string, binary, hex

I am trying to translate a String that contains a binary value (e.g. 000010001010011) to it's Hex value.(453)

I've been trying several options, but mostly I get a converted value of each individual character. (0=30 1=31)

I have a function that translates my input to binary code through a non-mathematical way, but through a series of "if, else if" statements. (the values are not calculated, because they are not standard.) The binary code is contained in a variable String "binOutput"

I currently have something like this:

```
        String bin = Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(binOutput));
```

But this does not work at all.

Comment: Wow, yo guys are fast! And it works! Thanks! But I have 1 issue remaining... when the numbers are larger it does not seem to work.(e.g. "1011000010001010011101010110110011001000010011111" should become 16114EAD9909F)

Comment: The problem is that the value does not fit in an `int`. Try `String bin = Long.toHexString(Long.parseLong(binOutput, 2));` If it gets too big for even a long (64 bits), then you're going to have to break `binOutput` into smaller strings and do each piece separately.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try using `Integer.parseInt(binOutput, 2)` instead of `Integer.parseInt(binOutput)`

Comment: Good answer, thanks, and what if I want "00000001" to be output as "01", not just only "1" ?

Comment: @RRTW - Are you asking about the inverse problem: converting an integer value to a string? This can be done in a variety of ways: `Integer.toString()`, `String.format`, and a few others. Your requirement is not clear. Do you always want a leading zero? Do you always want at least two digits? Something else?

Comment: Yes I want leading zero always :-), as your hint, I'll try done this with String.format, thanks~

Comment: @RRTW - If you want to format a non-negative integer value as a binary string with a leading zero, you can simply use `"0" + Integer.toString(value, 2)`. (That will generate "00" for zero, so you might want a special check for that case.)

Answer (score 2):

Ted Hopp beat me to it, but here goes anyway:

```
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ cat test.java; java test 000010001010011
public class test {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
   System.out.println("The value of " + args[i] + " is " +
    Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(args[i], 2)));
  }
 }
}
The value of 000010001010011 is 453
```