# split string in Java without delimiter, do math, then recombine

Tags: java, android, string, split

I have one very long string of numbers, and I need to convert it into binary. However, sometimes it can be so long that my system (Android phone) cannot handle it even as a Long.

So I need to break up the string in half, do the binary conversion on each individual half, then recombine both halves as the output string.

My problem is pretty much as described here by Ted Hopp:
[Translating a String containing a binary value to Hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759999/translating-a-string-containing-a-binary-value-to-hex-java)

I need some clues on how I'd go about this . . .

Comment: Did you try Tedd solution? same code applies for android program also.

Answer (score 5):

Have you considered using a standard Java BigInteger?

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/math/BigInteger.html

Comment: I ended up doing this, and it works: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.math/Bytes2Str.html

Comment: This converts a decimal to a binary:
big_decimal.toString(2);

but how would I convert a binary back to a decimal?

Comment: nm . . . I solved it finally . . . code below:
BigInteger big = new BigInteger(binary_val,2);

octal.setText(big.toString(8));
decimal.setText(big.toString(10));
hex.setText(big.toString(16));