# Take the Binary From Text Area and then Converting to Hexa

Tags: java

I want to take a binary in the text area and convert it to hex. When calculated using the calculator, result is "E0AC882AA428B6B8", but with my code result is "30".

```
String str = txtXOR.getText();
char[] chars = str.toCharArray();

StringBuffer hex = new StringBuffer();
int x = chars.length;

for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
  hex.append(Integer.toHexString((int)chars[i]));
  txtXORToHexa.setText(Integer.toHexString((int) chars[i]));
}
```

Could someone point out where I have gone wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759999/translating-a-string-containing-a-binary-value-to-hex

Comment: You're trying to convert each and every binary digit to its Hex equivalent. You'll have to treat the entire collection of digits to be a whole number.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Hex to a binary string in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246326/convert-hex-to-a-binary-string-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [Integer#parseInt(String s, int radix)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) with base 2 to parse the binary string and then use `toHexString` to get the Hex String:

```
String binaryStr = txtXOR.getText();
int number = Integer.parseInt(binaryStr, 2);
String hexStr = Integer.toHexString(number);
txtXORToHexa.setText(hexStr);
```

In case you must support very large number you can use [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html):

```
String binaryStr = txtXOR.getText();
BigInteger number = new BigInteger(binaryStr, 2);
String hexStr = number.toString(16);
txtXORToHexa.setText(hexStr);
```

Comment: thanks Aviram, if the binary value is short, the code works, but if the binary value is very long, error message appearsError: For input string: e.g "1101100011100100110110001101010011001100110100001101110011010100", I've tried to replace with Long.parseLong(str, 2); but still error,

Comment: Edited with solution for big numbers

Comment: wow, it works, now, I can go to the next step of construction program, and I really like this forum, My questions were answered very quickly,
thanks a lot Aviram Segal