# Converting a large binary string to hexadecimal

Tags: java

I have a binary string:

```
1010010111100101100010101010011011010001111100000010101000000000010000000111110111100"
```

How can I convert it to a hex string?

I tried with the wrapper classes `Long` and `Integer`, but it didn’t work for me, throwing a `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: Calculate the decimal value then use Integer.toHexString(value);

Comment: possible duplicate of [Translating a String containing a binary value to Hex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759999/translating-a-string-containing-a-binary-value-to-hex)  - This was the very first Google result using `java Convert Binary String to Hex String`

Comment: @JohnB The answer there refers to using int / long, which are too small in this instance.

Answer (score 11):

You need to use `BigInteger` for this - the number is too big to fit in a primitive value. The biggest number that can be stored in a `long` is 9223372036854775807, whereas the equivalent value in decimal of this binary string is much bigger, 25069592479040759763832764. That's why you're getting the `NumberFormatException`.

So with `BigInteger`:

```
String s = "1010010111100101100010101010011011010001111100000010101000000000010000000111110111100";
BigInteger b = new BigInteger(s, 2);
System.out.println(b.toString(16));
```

...which gives:

```
14bcb154da3e0540080fbc
```

Comment: WARNING - if you use the same method for binary strings that may begin with zeros, they may be dropped when converting to hex.

Answer (score 2):

As the length of your binary String may exceed the capacity of an Integer or Long, it's best to use BigInteger. Remember that in Java an int is always 32 bits, and a long 64 bits.

```
String binaryString = "1010010111100101100010101010011011010001111100000010101000000000010000000111110111100";
String hexString = new BigInteger(binaryString, 2).toString(16);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static String convertBinaryToHex(String binInPut) {
    int chunkLength = binInPut.length() / 4, startIndex = 0, endIndex = 4;
    String chunkVal = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < chunkLength; i++) {
        chunkVal = binInPut.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
         System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(chunkVal, 2)));
        startIndex = endIndex;
        endIndex = endIndex + 4;
    }

    return binInPut;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using big numbers:

```
String hexString = new BigInteger(binaryString, 2).toString(16);
```

Comment: BigInteger will trim leading zeros. This can be a problem if the bin string start with "00"

Answer (score 0):

I use this

```
fun String.binToHex(): String {
    val out = StringBuilder()
    val outArray = this.deviceInParts(4)
    outArray.forEach {
        if (it == "0000") out.append('0')
        if (it == "0001") out.append('1')
        if (it == "0010") out.append('2')
        if (it == "0011") out.append('3')
        if (it == "0100") out.append('4')
        if (it == "0101") out.append('5')
        if (it == "0110") out.append('6')
        if (it == "0111") out.append('7')
        if (it == "1000") out.append('8')
        if (it == "1001") out.append('9')
        if (it == "1010") out.append('A')
        if (it == "1011") out.append('B')
        if (it == "1100") out.append('C')
        if (it == "1101") out.append('D')
        if (it == "1110") out.append('E')
        if (it == "1111") out.append('F')
    }
    return out.toString()
}

fun String.deviceInParts(parts: Int): ArrayList<String> {
    val outArray = arrayListOf<String>()
    for (i in 0 until this.length step parts) {
        outArray.add(this.subString(i, parts))
    }
    return outArray
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).